# Binding dropdown to filter gridview but gridview has no sqlsource set

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I'm trying to enable some dropdowns which can filter the data displayed in the gridview so it's exact match to what's in the dropdowns. Due to how I've got the edit/delete/update functions working on the gridview. Below is my gridview setup so you can see how the data is pulled in etc.

Examples of syntax is what I'm looking for in order to try and resolve this:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Manager.aspx.cs" Inherits="com.tortoise.Admin.AdminViews.Manager" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1 {
            height: 311px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button Text="Upload" OnClick = "Upload" runat="server" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataAdmins" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TortoiseDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Zoopla] WHERE (([Weeks] = @Weeks) AND ([PropStatus] = @PropStatus))" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" OnSelecting="SqlDataAdmins_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Weeks" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="PropStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ZooplaURL" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="HouseNumber" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PropAddress" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Town" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="County" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Postcode" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PropType" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Beds" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PropStatus" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Weeks" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ZooplaURL" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_HouseNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PropAddress" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Town" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_County" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Postcode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PropType" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Beds" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_PropStatus" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Weeks" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Button ID="Logout" runat="server" OnClick="Logout_Click" Text="Logout" />
        <br />
        Filter By Weeks:
          <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="Weeks" DataValueField="Weeks">
              <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        Filter By Status:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="PropStatus" DataValueField="PropStatus">
            <asp:ListItem>For Sale</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Withdrawn</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Sold/SSTC</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ZooplaProperties" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TortoiseDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PropStatus] FROM [Zoopla]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TortoiseDBZoopla" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TortoiseDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Weeks] FROM [Zoopla]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
            OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records has been added." AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

            <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ZooplaURL" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblZooplaURL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ZooplaURL") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtZooplaURL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ZooplaURL") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HouseNumber" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblHouseNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HouseNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHouseNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HouseNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PropAddress" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPropAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPropAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropAddress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Town" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTown" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Town") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTown" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Town") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="County" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCounty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("County") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCounty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("County") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ZooplaURL" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPostcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Postcode") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Postcode") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PropType" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPropType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropType") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPropType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropType") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Beds" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBeds" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Beds") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBeds" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Beds") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PropStatus" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPropStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPropStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropStatus") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weeks" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblWeeks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Weeks") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeeks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Weeks") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150"/>
</Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="ExportData" runat="server" OnClick="ExportData_Click" Text="Export Visible Data" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using CsvHelper;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace com.tortoise.Admin.AdminViews
{
    public partial class Manager : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            Session["New"].ToString();
        }

        else
        {

        }

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateZoopla"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT");
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["New"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx");
    }

    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Upload and save the file
        string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[12] { new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("ZooplaURL", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("HouseNumber",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("PropAddress",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Town",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("County",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Postcode",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Price",typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("PropType",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Beds",typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("PropStatus",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Weeks",typeof(int))  });

        string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);

        foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                    i++;
                }

            }
        }

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Zoopla";
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void BindSubjectData()
    {
        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Zoopla";
                cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    GridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false;
                }
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    //called on row edit command




    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    protected void ExportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {

            con.Open();
            string sql = ("SELECT [ID], [HouseNumber], [PropAddress], [Town], [County], [PostCode] FROM Zoopla;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            string filename = "filtered-addresses.xml";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
            dgGrid.DataBind();
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
            this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }

    }


    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string HouseNumber = (row.FindControl("txtHouseNumber") as TextBox).Text;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateZoopla"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "UPDATE");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HouseNumber", HouseNumber);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    protected void SqlDataAdmins_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateZoopla"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "DELETE");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        this.BindGrid();

    }

    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,     EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your call to this.BindGrid() from Page_Load to Page_PreRenderComplete.  Page_Load occurs before the DropDownList selection change leaving you to lag one postback behind.

Comment: What is the defect or issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is linking up the drop down filter list with the gridview data. The data source is not set against the gridview line but instead is applied on a post back as seen in the code above. I've got the drop down list with items etc, but when selecting them they don't filter down the gridviews data.